# Shorten code automatically in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I was wondering if it was possible to shorten code automatically in the last version of xcode. You know, when you press on the side of a void method for example and the (...) appear, and you have a shorter page. Is there a command to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the Editor>Code Folding menu and you'll see all your options for this, along with the keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut is cmnd + shift + option + left arrow key. This will collapse all functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can press `command + alt + left cursor key` on your keyboard to fold your codes or press `command + alt + right cursor key` to unfold. Make sure your pointer is inside of the curly brackets.